# PCL Storage throwing an error the second time I try to read a file

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am brand new to Xamarin and still learning the ropes so bear with me. I am using the PCLStorage library (https://github.com/dsplaisted/pclstorage) to read and write to a json file.

I have set up static classes in my PCL so that I can call them from the native code (not sure if that's the best way of doing it, see below). The rootFolder being passed in is FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage.

```
public static async Task<string> ReadFileContent(string fileName, IFolder rootFolder)
{
    IFile file = null;
    string text = null;

    var files = await rootFolder.GetFilesAsync();
    file = files.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == fileName);


    if (file != null)
    {
        try
        {
            text = await file.ReadAllTextAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            var x = exception.Message;
        }

    }

    return text;
}



public static async Task WriteFileContent(string fileName, IFolder rootFolder, string content)
        {
            ExistenceCheckResult exist = await rootFolder.CheckExistsAsync(fileName);

            if (exist == ExistenceCheckResult.FileExists)
            {
                IFile file = await rootFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
                await file.WriteAllTextAsync(content);
            }
            else
            {
                IFile file = await rootFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                await file.WriteAllTextAsync(content);
            }
        }
```

This works perfectly when I first run the Android app. It reads the files multiple times and every thing works. However later on I fire off an intent which takes the user to a webpage. When the user is directed back to the app to a different Activity it stops working. The "await rootFolder.GetFilesAsync();" throws an unhandled exception with no more information than that.

Is there something i'm missing when resuming the app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you get an unhandled exception, the first thing you should try to do is add a try/catch (or use the debugger) to get the actual exception

Comment: I have tried that, it goes into break mode even within the try block, for some reason the exception is not caught...

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with this code? "However later on I fire off an intent which takes the user to a webpage. When the user is directed back to the app to a different Activity it stops working.", sounds like that your problem is with the transaction between different intents.

Comment: Hi Grace, yeah I think you might be right however the intent is working as far as the OnCreate method is running within the correct activity when the user is returned. It's just when this library is called it seems to break. Maybe I am missing something when handling the Intent.